# View Years Alive in Months

Tags: c++, time

I am trying to create a program that finds out how many months they have been alive, but have been running into some issues. Here is my function so far:

```
int getResult(int year, month, day, endResult)
{
    int thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay;

    year = thisYear - year;

    year *= 12;
}
```

And what I'm trying to accomplish would show an output like:

```
Output: 
What year were you born? 
1989 
What month were you born? 
5 
What day were you born? 
23 
You are x months old.
```

I was going to continue with months but then I realized, what if the month they were born is  in after this month or before? So, if anyone has any tips on how to calculate that, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Why can't the result come out negative? "You will be born in... months."

Comment: @KerrekSB Thats not my issue... at all.

Comment: By the way, when you get an answer that actually answers your question, you might wanna accept it (with the little check mark on the bottom of the answer votes)

Comment: I am also stuck on how to fetch the current date since I have never worked with anything like that before.

Comment: @Shahbaz: OK, sorry, let me formulate this in a more constructive manner: When dealing with time, watch out that the specification is correct and precise. At the end of may, your problem might have multiple answers, depending on the definition of "month" (any 30 days, same day in month). And when the input is "1988", "2" and "29", it gets even worse. So be sure to get the specification right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see. First, let's say now is:

```
year_now and month_now
```

and your birthday is:

```
year_birth and month_birth
```

Now, we go case by case:

- `month_now == month_birth`: as you have already computed:

  ```
  months_old = (year_now-year_birth)*12
  ```
- `month_now > month_birth`: easily, you have:

  ```
  months_old = (year_now-year_birth)*12 + (month_now-month_birth)
  ```
- `month_now < month_birth`: in this case, `(year_now-year_birth)*12` gives you more months then necessary, and you have to subtract:

  ```
  months_old = (year_now-year_birth)*12 - (month_birth-month_now)
  ```

Now if you look carefully, you will see that they are all in fact the same formula:

```
months_old = (year_now-year_birth)*12 + (month_now-month_birth)
```

(in the third case, `month_now-month_birth` is negative)

Answer (score 0):

```
months = (thisyear-years)*12+(thisMonth-months)
if(months < 0)
    System.out.println("Invalid info")
else{
    //DO YOUR THANG BRO 
}
```